# How to check if "Allow management of all files" is allowed?

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage, android-permissions

There are basically 3 types of storage permissions in the android app settings: 
[image]

My app requires the highest permission, so I use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in `manifest.xml`.

Now I want to block the whole app, if the permission is not granted. So I tried using this code to check, if the highest permission is granted, but it **always returns false**.

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

I also tried using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but it also returns true at the second option "Allow access to media only".

**Conclusion**

I am looking for a `boolean` function:

- Returning **true**, if "Allow management of all files" is selected
- Returning **false**, if "Allow access to media only" is selected
- Returning **false**, if "Deny" is selected

Thank you.

Comment: does your app work when user selected `Allow access to media only`.

Comment: @VishalBeep No, it doesn't.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Environment.isExternalStorageManager().
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me

```
    fun hasAllFilesAccess(context: Context): Boolean {
    val appOpsManager = context.getSystemService(APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
    try {
        val app = context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.packageName, 0)
        return appOpsManager.unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
            "android:manage_external_storage",
            app.uid,
            context.packageName
        ) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: NoSuchMethodError) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```