# How to check if an app is a Media Management App?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Starting with Android 12, gallery-like apps have to request the MANAGE_MEDIA permission and the user can be quickly redirected to the device settings with `Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_MANAGE_MEDIA)` to set an app as a Media management app.

How to check during runtime if the user really made the app a Media management app? It doesn't seem to work with checking MANAGE_MEDIA permission, nor have I found an alternative for `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()`, that is used by file managers. I basically need an alternative of [How to check if "Allow management of all files" is allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747444/how-to-check-if-allow-management-of-all-files-is-allowed) for galleries.

Answer (score 1):

found it, it is `MediaStore.canManageMedia()`